# TypeError: _this2 is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to use the value of radio buttons. They are rendered inside a **Materialize modal**. I've bound a function `renderRemarkOption`. But whenever I click on the radio button, it shows **TypeError: _this2 is undefined**

```
selectChangeHandler(e){
    // console.log(e.target.name,e.target.value)
    if (typeof e === 'string' || e instanceof String){
        // alert(e)

    }
    else{
        const input_name = e.target.name;
        const input_value = e.target.value;
        if(!this.isBlank(input_value,'Field '+input_name+' is required'))
            {
                return false;
            }

        if(!this.isPreviousStateSame(input_name,input_value,this.props.lead)){

            if(input_name=='lead_status')
            {
                this.props.updateLeadProps({name: input_name,value:input_value},'UPDATE_LEAD');

                {/*if(this.props.remark.text=='')
                {
                    alert('')
                    return false;
                }*/}

                console.log('presalesid',this.props.lead)

                if(this.next_followup_datetime == undefined) this.next_followup_datetime = this.props.lead.initial_score_timestamp;
                let pre_sales_ids = !this.props.isBulkProcessing.is_bulk_process? [this.props.lead.id] : this.props.isBulkProcessing.ids;
                this.props.postFetch(
                    urls.post_leads_remark,
                    {
                        pre_sales_ids:pre_sales_ids,
                        lead_status:this.props.remark.type ,
                        initial_score_timestamp:this.next_followup_datetime,
                        remark:this.props.remark.text
                    },
                    'POST_LEADS_REMARK'
                );

                return false;
            }
            if(input_name=='options'){
                alert(input_value)
                this.setState({chosen_remark:input_value})
            }

            if(this.props.isBulkProcessing.is_bulk_process)
            {
                this.props.postFetch(
                    urls.update_leads,
                    {
                        pre_sales_ids : this.props.isBulkProcessing.ids,
                        name:input_name,
                        value:input_value
                    },
                    'UPDATE_LEAD'
                );

                //console.log('bulk processin g',pre_sales_ids);
            }

            else{
                this.props.postFetch(
                    urls.LEAD_BASIC_INFO_UPDATE,
                    {
                        pre_sales_id:this.props.lead.id,
                        name:input_name,
                        value:input_value
                    },
                    'UPDATE_LEAD'
                );
            }

        }
    }
}


renderRemarkOption(data) {
    let template =[];
    this.props.controllSelectData.remarks_content[data].forEach(function(item,index){
        template.push(<p key={index}><input className="with-gap" name="options" type="radio" id={index} onChange={(e)=>this.selectChangeHandler(e)}/><label htmlFor={index} key={index} >{item}</label></p>)
    })
    this.setState({remark_content:template},function(){
        $(`#${data}_modal`).modal('open');
    })

    return this.state.remark_content
}

render() {  
    return(
        <div className="col s12">
        <form >
         { 
          this.state['remark_content']
          }
         <div className="col s12 right remark-field">
            <Input type="textarea" name="remark"/> 
         </div>
         <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-button" type="submit" onClick={this.selectChangeHandler('not_reachable')}>Submit</a>
       </form>
     </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Really not sur of what your are trying to do, are you able to provide a jsfidlle ?

Comment: Is your `onClick=` with so many spaces before the function name? Can you format the inserted code properly?

Comment: You'll have to show more of your code ([mcve]). Specifically, the way that you bind the function. You also call a method called `selectChangeHandler` in the onClick but you only show a method called `renderRemarkOption` so it's very hard to tell what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: renderRemarkOption is used to create a list of radio button. These radio buttons are then pushed to a state and the state is used in the MODAL to represent the list of radio buttons.
I wanted to retrieve the value radio button is selected from the list presented in the modal. Therefore, adding onClick seems appropriate in the <input> tag of radio buttons.

Comment: `_react2.default.createElement('input', { className: 'with-gap', name: 'options', type: 'radio', id: index, onChange: function onChange(e) {
                            return _this2.selectChangeHandler(e);
                        } })`

This is shown when clicked on the error in console.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not passing a callback to the `onClick` prop, instead you are executing the function:

```
<a className="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-button" type="submit" onClick={this.selectChangeHandler('not_reachable')}>Submit</a>
```

Should be

```
<a className="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-button" type="submit" onClick={() => this.selectChangeHandler('not_reachable')}>Submit</a>
```